# How to crop complex (vector) graphics in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, crop

I have to crop complex (lots of strokes) floral shapes in Illustrator. To date I could not find a method that just works without manual labor and fixing afterwards.

[image]

This is graphic I'm trying to crop with that green rectangle. Using **Pathfinder** *Divide* and *Outline* do work to some extend. But I have to restore stroke width and color manually and delete lines that.

Is there any alternative to these Illustrator tools. I'm also happy to switch applications to perform the crop in a way that keeps stroke width and colors.

Thank you

Comment: Group the artwork, and add the rectangle as a clipping mask, or use the Shape Builder tool if you actually want to remove and cut away the outer parts.

Comment: yes well you can not actually do it. You can hide the extra, oor you can rebuild all strokes as double edges. This is not a illustrator limitation its a vector limitation

Answer (score 3):

@Hans
Have you tried creating a "clipping mask"? If you did and the clipping mask isn't taking, you might need to make the artwork a compound shape and then apply the clipping mask.

Answer (score 3):

Select what you have there.. *including the green rectangle*.

- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key
- click-drag across everything you do *not* want.